# Solving a system of equations involving smooth functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, partial-derivative, holomorphic-functions

This is a follow-up question of my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2062964/solving-a-system-of-equations-involving-holomorphic-functions). Suppose $h_{i\overline{j}}$, where $1\leq i, j\leq n$, are functions defined on $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $h_{i\overline{j}}$ are smooth when viewed as functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$
and $H=(h_{i\overline{j}})$ is a Hermitian positive definite matrix. I wonder if it is always possible to find smooth functions $p_1,..., p_n$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ such that 
$$\frac{\partial p_i}{\partial z_j}+\overline{\frac{\partial p_j}{\partial z_i}}=h_{i\overline{j}}\mbox{ and }
\frac{\partial p_i}{\partial \overline{z}_j}
-\frac{\partial p_j}{\partial \overline{z}_i}=0.$$
In the previous question, I require $p_i$ to be holomorphic, which seems to be too strong.